# An adjective to describe "being at sea"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that describes the fact that a ship is sailing at sea. Much as "afoot" describes a person being in the state of walking. I was hoping "asail" would be a word, but can't find it from Google.

The word would replace the square brackets in the following example:

> In Plato's ship of state metaphor, a ship is [sailing at sea], helmed by a captain ...

Comment: *asea*: at sea http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a-sea The word also means 'seaward'.

Comment: Oh okay, that's probably even better than afloat :).

Comment: *Afloat* does not have to be on the sea, it could be in the bath tub even.

Comment: ... But alake/ acanal / areservoir / abathtub are sadly not available.

Comment: Without further context, I think the choice between the various suggestions here is not obvious. '[Out] at sea' itself (the captain wouldn't be 'helming' if the ship weren't sailing) seems the obvious choice, 'asea' being omitted from some quality dictionaries, doubtless because it is archaic.

Comment: Oh, I'm not worried about sounding archaistic, it's only for me. You're right, there's no particularly superior answer to this one. I'll use asea because it sounds cool :)

Comment: A ship is at sea with a captain at the helm. Generally, we say at the helm.

Comment: I would use "clueless", but that's just me.

Comment: Another option is "under weigh," which is a nautical version of _under way_ (influenced by the notion of "weighing"—that is, lifting—anchor), meaning in motion or in transit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [*afloat*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/afloat):

> 1. floating
> 2. out at sea

Comment: Oh, silly me, I know that word; I don't know why I didn't think of it. You and Elian gave the same answer, I'll accept yours simply because you answered about 9 seconds quicker :P.

Comment: Well aware, cheers. It wouldn't let me click it until a certain period of time had elapsed - I only found out now that there was a grace period.

Comment: +1 and much better than *adrift*.

Comment: The vessel is at sea, not out at sea, really. And floating and afloat? Hmm, not really. A ship can be afloat and not at all at sea or out at sea.

Answer (score 2):

“Afloat,” though, all too conspicuously lacks any connotation of purposeful motion. The nautical term you seek is, I believe, “underway”:

> a. *Naut.* Of a vessel: under way; having begun to move through the water. [OED]

Comment: Well, indicating motion isn't necessarily important for Plato's ship of state metaphor: the captain is a deaf idiot with no idea how to sail; the crew no better; it's a miracle they're even afloat, let alone underway :). Still, +1 for another good word.

Answer (score 1):

What comes to mind is [**afloat**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afloat).

> In Plato's ship of state metaphor, a ship is *afloat*, helmed by a captain ...

afloat: floating on water; being at sea

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be simply *at sea*: "In Plato's ship of state metaphor, a ship is *at sea*, helmed by a captain . . ."

Comment: "asea" is just a contraction of "at sea".

Answer (score 0):

I submit for everyone's approval, remove the word "is" and use the phrase, "while under sail".

> a ship **while under sail**, helmed by a captain ...

Answer (score -1):

It it common to say "on duty" but that changes the metaphore.